# java spring-boot Error: "cannot resolve symbol jdbc"

Tags: java, spring, jetty, hsqldb

i have read

- [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

and searched the web for: "cannot resolve symbol jdbc" with zero results.

I changed pom.xml but gives Error `Dependency 'org.xerial:hsqldb-jdbc:' not found`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- bellow is not working (red in IDE): -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version></version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And tried much much more.

What else i could do and try?

So far I had only programmed in finished Spring applications. This should be [my first Spring application](https://gist.github.com/sl5net/c2ec6bfcce2405d5204cd087fe7ce23e) that I write from the beginning (defaults: Jetty, hsqldb).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure where you got this `hsqldb-jdbc` dependency but it seems that it is no longer in `org.xerial` group. You can see it [in MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial) that there is no such dependency.

As far as I understand, you need this dependency to succesfully connect to the HSQLDB. To connect to database, do following:

1. Add HSQLDB without `test` scope as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Create application.properties in your `resources` folder

For on-disk database:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testdb 
spring.datasource.username=sa 
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

For in-memory database:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

3. Create entities
4. Create Repositories
5. Test it all out

Take a look at this [Spring Boot HSQLDB integration tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hsqldb) for more

Comment: i get "Cannot resolve class 'JDBCDriver'" seems connected with maybe this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001677580-JDBC-driver-class-not-resolved-in-Spring-Boot-application-yml-during-code-analysis , https://www.programmersought.com/article/87461736589/

Comment: I updated my answer with point #1. You are trying to add HSQLDB with scope "test" which means that it will be enabled only for tests. What you actually need is to have this dependency for all scopes

Comment: You have it in your pom with <scope>test</scope>. Remove this scope and refresh dependencies. Then you won't have "Cannot resolve class 'JDBCDriver'" error in application.properties

Comment: implemented but error still there: https://i.imgur.com/VlaypyI.png

Comment: Well that's another error with your implementation of `UserDaoImpl`. I would suggest you go through this tutorial and adjust code accordingly: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hsqldb

Comment: this tutorial using version 2.4.0 that produce errors. in my pom i use 2.3.2 that seems give not early errors: https://i.imgur.com/YK17nFA.png

Comment: I looked at the baeldung.com page and it has a small but significant error. The Server start command should be like this: java -cp ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:testdb --dbname0.testdb